# loading key and value pairs in a file into a Properties object and print out all key and value pairs using Properties.list(PrintWriter p) method

Tags: java, properties, printwriter

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to load all key and value pairs in a file into a Properties object and print out all key and value pairs using Properties.list(PrintWriter p) method. Below is the code I came up with.

However, when I run the code, the IDE did not output anything. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

```
Properties p1 = new Properties();
InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
p1.load(is1);
PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(System.out);
p1.list(pw1);
```

Comment: is your file.txt file is empty ?

Comment: What is path of your File.txt? Test with full path of text file.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: @PritamTiwari I have checked, the file is not empty

Comment: @Rahul I will , thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @fge java standard edition 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try implementing the code in the below way:

```
            Properties p1 = new Properties();
            InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
            p1.load(is1);
            PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            System.out.println("printing property values");
            p1.list(pw1);
            System.out.println(p1.getProperty("1"));
            System.out.println(p1.getProperty("2"));
```

further to add more to your code,if you wish to print all the keys and values togehter,you can also choose to use enumeration in the below way:

```
        Properties p1 = new Properties();
        InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
        p1.load(is1);
        PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        System.out.println("printing property values");
        p1.list(pw1);
        Enumeration<?> e = p1.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = p1.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
        }

This will get you all the keys and respective values together on the console.
```

Answer (score 1):

`Properties p1 = new Properties();
        InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
        p1.load(is1);
        PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        p1.list(pw1);
        pw1.flush();
        pw1.close();`

You need to invoke flush() on the PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

you can also display them in this way:

```
    Properties p1 = new Properties();
    InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream("src\\File.txt");
    p1.load(is1);

    for(Object key:p1.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(key+"="+p1.get(key));
    }
```

or:

```
System.out.println(p1.toString());
```